# Cannot resolve the SNAPSHOT dependency deployed via Maven deploy-file

Tags: maven, spring-boot, nexus

I have a problem with Nexus dependency resolution. Nexus version is 3.13.

I have a project "A" which is used as a library across different projects.
I am trying to create 
- SNAPSHOT versions to be used for DEV environment
- RELEASE versions will be used after code freeze and to deploy other environments.

I deploy the project "A" as a snapshot to a maven hosted repository(jar file, snapshot repository). I tried "deploy plugin" 3.0.0-M1 and 2.8.2 with uniqueVersion=false. But every time a timestamp is added to the artefacts in Nexus(jar and POM files). I have no issue with timestamp but I cannot resolve the project from other projects.

When I use "LATEST" as the version then the following is the response

"The POM for filename:jar:X.Y.Z-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available". The POM and JAR is in the repository, but the POM file contains the timestamp suffix as well.

I don't have any problems with release repository for the same project.

Any idea?

Edit :

I used uniqueVersion only for version 2.8.2, for the others there is already an error(or warning).

To deploy project "A", I use the following maven command

```
mvn  deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=target/my-library-0.0.X-SNAPSHOT.jar -DpomFile=pom.xml -DrepositoryId=nexus -Durl=http://my-ip-address/repository/my-library-snapshots.
```

The POM contained almost nothing actually the usual IDs and a dependency to Lombok.

From the project B, I use only the following

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>Some Group IDs</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-library</artifactId>
  <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

Instead of LATEST, I also tried expilicitly giving version number in nexus.

Comment: The first thing related to maven-deploy-plugin 3.0.0-M1 you have not read the [plugin page](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) cause for uniqueVersion is simply stated that this parameter has been removed from the plugin. Furthermore can you show both pom file from your project which is creating the project "A" and the other which is consuming the dependency "A"...

Comment: I updated the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It was related to my settings.xml file. I added another element under "profile" element called "id"

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
```